# Why does my website not appear on google search when it has a php redirect?

Tags: php, html, google-search

I have a page on my website, that has some PHP code before the `<html>` tag is declared. The code is something like this:

```
<?php
  if (!isset($_COOKIE["loggedin"])) {
    header("location: login.php");
  }
?>
```

Basically, this code means that if the user is not logged in, then the user would be redirected to a page called `login.php`.

Now, since google would not read the php, it would consider the page as `login.php` if the user is not logged in. What should I do in order to make this page available on Google?

Comment: look for googlebot with stristr in `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`, btw you should exit after a redirect header, and `$_COOKIE["loggedin"]` doesn't look very secure

Comment: You should consider this guide : https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/get-started